# C# SharePoint 2013 CSOM multi-authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, sharepoint, ntlm, csom

We have our on-premises SharePoint2013 and it has multiple authentication methods enabled (NTLM and FBA).

Now when I try to authenticate to this server with CSOM and try to get a List for example, the server returns: "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.", though I do have permissions (have full control and whatever is needed) and SharePoint provides me with FedAuth cookie. Checked out the requests with fiddler, seems like CSOM can't access client.svc service even though it is started and running? Code sample:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Security;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace TestConsoleTemp
{
public class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
        using (SP.ClientContext context = new SP.ClientContext("https://mywebsite.com"))
        {
            var cc = new CredentialCache();
            var passWord = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in "password".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
            cc.Add(new Uri("https://myportal.sis.lt"), "NTLM", new NetworkCredential("username", passWord, "domain"));
            context.Credentials = cc;
            context.ExecutingWebRequest += new EventHandler<SP.WebRequestEventArgs>(clientContext_ExecutingWebRequest);
            var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("listName");
            context.Load(list);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
    }
    static void clientContext_ExecutingWebRequest(object sender, SP.WebRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
    } 
  }
}
```

Same code works with other servers where we have only NTLM authentication or on cloud (Office365) even without adding the header.

Could someone explain why CSOM does not work when both NTLM and FBA are enabled?

Answer (score 1):

We faced the same issue, for us it was related to the login page and authentication, If you are using a custom login page follow the steps described [here](http://www.godwinpaul.com/sharepoint/2014/sharepoint-2013-csom-error-custom-login-page-forms-based-mixed-mode-authentication) to get the CSOM working. If you are not using a custom login page, you could still try the same activities with the SharePoint default login page.

Here is the relevant code:

```
context.ExecutingWebRequest += new EventHandler<WebRequestEventArgs>((obj, e) => {
    e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");   
});
```

When you use Network credentials on a site collection that has FBA enabled, you must explicitly tell the auth method not to use forms based auth with that header `X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED`.

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh124553(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: We do have a custom login page, just wondering if it's possible to authenticate without modifying SharePoint site itself, because it's not always possible to do so in case you're developing for a client and have no control of it.

Comment: I also wanted the same for my SharePoint site, however the CSOM is unable to access the login page in 15 hives folder , and hence the error. I did find this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2014/02/06/sharepoint-2013-csom-call-from-web-part-fails-with-401-for-all-users.aspx) but have not tried it on my system. May be this helps you.